# Is wrapping SOAP/JMS as REST using API Mgmt. tools practical?

Tags: api, rest, apigee, wso2-api-manager

Is wrapping SOAP/JMS as RESTful API using API Mgmt. tools practical?

API management tools like apigee and wso2 –am claim support for exposing SOAP services as REST-JSON but practically I find it difficult to map the two and do not see a value add that we can bring say by exposing all our SOAP/JMS resources over a Restful API Mgmt. tool. 
SOAP services are structurally very different from REST where you can have a set of multiple operations with possible lot of request and response elements mapping to business cases usually.

REST on the other hand is based on four HTTP verbs GET, POST, PUT and DELETE which are to be handled tactfully to handle defined resources.
What design principle can we use to do the mapping?

For example, Implementing above translation might require adding a lot of xml content to your HTTP header for a GET request and later processing it which is not a standard implementation of HTTP and REST.

Thanks,
Wajid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Ian said, SOAP services often do not map directly into RESTful APIs. I do not know of any SOAP-to-REST conversion tools provided by any vendor that will automatically create a beautiful, RESTful API from a set of SOAP services.

Assuming you intend to expose your RESTful API to many developers, and/or care about how usable (beautiful, I'd argue) it is, my recommendation would be to design the RESTful API by analyzing the resources you are trying to encapsulate in the RESTful API without worrying about the SOAP services you have. Assuming you can map the domain into resources, you can come up with a usable, intuitive RESTful interface.

Then, when you are happy with the RESTful API, use the SOAP services as building blocks. The API Management layer should, as Ian explained, help you convert your RESTful input into SOAP requests, mash up multiple calls, extract information from the responses into your chosen response payloads, and help you secure and scale your API. If you find you need to compromise on your RESTful API design due to inability to compose the SOAP building blocks into the desired RESTful interface, at least you will understand where you are compromising.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible automatically, at least not without AI.

First you have to split every operation name into 2 parts: a resource with an IRI and a VERB.

For example:

- `GetLastTradePrice` will be at least `GET /lastTradePrice` or with further transformation `GET tradePrices/last`
- `Hello` will be `GET /greeting?name="{name}"`
- `CreateUser`, `GetUserName`, `DeleteUserById` will be `POST /users`, `GET /users/{id}?fields="name"`, `DELETE /users/{id}`

If you want to have nice IRIs to debug your router, and link builder server side, then you need a strict concept or AI to do this. If not then your luck that the IRI structure does not really matter, so you can use `/resources/{id}` for every resource. For example `/users` can be `/resources/static:1` and `/users/123` can be `/resources/123`. If every resource has a unique id in your system. If not, then you have to use unique subcategories, for example `/resources/avz5ag6u:123`. Without an AI, or some strict naming concept in your SOAP service, you won't be able to reuse IRIs like `/users` by `POST`, `GET`, or `/users/{id}` by `PUT`, `GET`, `DELETE`, but that's not a tragedy since by REST every resource can have multiple IRIs. Just be aware that they are unique...

The problem is with the meaning part of these links (VERB + IRI). By REST you navigate checking the meta-data related to links, for example [IANA link relations](http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml) with [vendor specific MIME types](http://restcookbook.com/Resources/using-custom-content-types/) by [HAL](http://stateless.co/hal_specification.html), or `rdf:Property`s described by a custom [RDF vocab](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-schema/) by [Hydra](http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/hydra/) (if we are talking about REST JSON ofc). I think it is possible to generate the parameter and return value validation/description part from the `XSD` you have in your `WSDL` file, but you will have a hard time with the link meta-data. For that you'll need an AI. If you are lucky your SOAP service already provides some RDF info, by such a service I think automatic mapping is possible, otherwise I don't think so, and anyways it will be a hard job. You won't be able to debug or improve the generated service, because the routes will use anonym IRIs or IRI templates.

So in most of the cases it is not possible to do this fully automatical. You need some strict operation naming concepts and/or already existing RDF descriptions to your SOAP service. Even with that it is a hard job to write a REST service generator I think. Without that you have to do some or more manual job, like annotating your SOAP service with REST specific things, or write some REST specific attributes into your WSDL file, and use them to generate the REST service. Now this is one part of the job.

The other part is reusing the business logic of your SOAP service. If you have a centered layout like clean, onion or hexagonal/ports&adapters, then it should be easy to add a new adapter for the REST deliver or port. If you don't use such architecture, then you have to write the whole REST service or a god class REST adapter manually.

In my opinion writing a SOAP -> REST generator does not worth the effort. It is easier to write a REST service manually.

Answer (score 0):

That's an excellent question.  REST is a very abused word.  Many (most maybe) SOAP services are transactional in nature and therefore are not ideally suited to a RESTful paradigm.  All that said, the religious debates over using REST for non RESTful services are a bit silly IMHO.

You can certainly use an API Management product for this (I work for an API Management company).  In truth though, it's rarely as simple as the vendors may claim.  Some products can declaratively mediate between SOAP and REST, but the resulting RESTful service will likely be ugly, you'll probably need to remove/add the SOAP document wrapping from around the edges of your response and request documents at the very least.  And when you start converting XML<->JSON, you'll run into all sorts of fun issues with things like Array to sequence mappings.

That said, a good API Management product (specifically a good API Gateway) will offer strong declarative capabilities to get you close, combined with more advanced mapping and mediation features to get you all the way to where you want to be.  If you pick the right product, you'll probably also get some nice orchestration capabilities for building composite APIs from multiple backend services.

If you want more information on this, please feel free to message me.  I don't think it's appropriate for me to give a commercial for my company in this forum.

Ian